# Urgent Validate Save-Post Hooks on Woo-commerce product entry form!

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to have the required validation on the product entry form for product descriptions (both long and short descriptions) with minimum and maximum character allowed on the Woocommerce site.

Expected Scenario

1. Admins/Shop Managers shouldn't be allowed to save the product draft or submit the product if they leave this field empty.
2. I want the required sign on the long and short description input field.
3. If possible I want to set minimum and maximum characters allowed on tet editor we have on Woo-commerce product entry form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to do it on the wp-admin dashboard or frontend?
If you plan to add it to the frontend, what plugin are you using for that?

Comment: I want this on the admin product entry page on woocommerce

Comment: You can write JS to check if the fields are filled or not and based on that disable/enable the save button. 
You can enqueue that JS using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: I couldn't do it